# ByteBuf packet size with string validating?

Tags: java, networking, netty

When I send a packet from server to client or vise-verse, I need to make sure that the packet is legal, I check the size of the received packet, and match it if the received packet's size is same as what it should be.

Every packet as an `opcode`, opcode is used to know what type of a packet it is, e.g opcode 2 is login packet.

So login packet has an opcode, and two strings.
username max length is 18, password max length is 12 for example, so the login packet's size must be 31.

But what happens when the username is less than 18? if my password is 10 and username is 4, my packet size will be 15 and will be illegal according to the system checks.

When I allocate the bytebuf size as 31, it will send with capacity of 31, but when it's received the capacity turns into 1024, no idea why.

What is it doing that and how should this be done?

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a stream based protocol. This means that the length of incoming bytebufs cannot be related to the length of the packet at the writing side. There are different ways to solve this, the most easy method would be attaching a length to your packets. You can do this with your own custom handlers, or use the handlers that are already build in into Netty. The following example shows you the pipeline for this configuration:

```
channelPipeline.addLast("framer", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(Short.MAX_VALUE,0,2,0,2));
channelPipeline.addLast("framer-prepender", new LengthFieldPrepender(2, false));
```

The arguments for [`LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) are:

- Max frame length
- Offset in receiving data for frame length
- Length in bytes of our length field
- Bytes to strip from the received message

The arguments for [`LengthFieldPrepender`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldPrepender.html) are:

- Length in bytes of our length field

When you add the above classes to your pipeline, you can use the `buf.  readableBytes()` to get the amount of bytes every packet contains.

Comment: What if I hash any string data? it will be a fixed size every time, is that a good solution?

Comment: If you are hashing your data, how can you get it back?

Comment: Ok i dont understand ur way, idk why but people told me when u send a string, u need to send it as a variable or something? what did he mean?

Comment: "A string dosn't have a set packet size as it's a variable size, therefore the packet is a variable size."